# How to keep Facebook login alive when integrating with your own log in?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I successfully set up Facebook log in to my web app (that has it's own login system too), but am wondering how to keep the FB connection alive for, say, publishing to their wall, in the following example of one of my log ins.

Here's the login process (I'm using the Facebook php SDK):

- FB user clicks login with Facebook' button instead of entering pass and email
- the facebook php SDK checks for their logged status, and then discovers they have authorised my app
- my app checks for existence of their FB id in my database, finds it, and so initiates the same login process as for an email/pass logged user...

  session_destroy();
  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id();

...then load user ID and first and last name from my database into session vars

It works fine and the user can use my app as if they'd logged with an email pass.

However, I now want to publish to their wall, but can't because the Facebook session was destroyed in my above log in process, so on the page where I want to publish to their wall, the Facebook php connection code tells me they aren't connected (which makes sense).

Can someone please throw some light on the correct way I should be doing this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Please get the values of session and make the login fb id alive.. (i.e)not to unset until you logout..

```
$facebook->getSession();
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply.  I currently use the $facebook->getUser() code when logging them in (I thought getSession was deprecated?), and then successfully get their profile etc using $fb_profile = $facebook->api('/me/?field=name,email').  So are you saying that a) there is a way to get the session of the Facebook id, and b) I should place it into a local var just before destroying and then setting the new session (to log user in), and then place the FB local var session info back into a session var after they are logged in?

Comment: I think I figured it out. On FB authentication, also do $FB_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); pass this local var to the function that logs people into my site once they are authenticated in my DB, then after session_destroy(); session_start(); etc place it into a session var: $_SESSION['FB_access_token']=$FB_access_token; In the main connect code for Facebook, add the check (before getUser()): if($_SESSION['FB_access_token']) $facebook->setAccessToken($_SESSION['FB_access_token']);  This successfully gives me access to the users info.  Any holes in my code that you can see?  Cheers